# set pointer to NULL after free the heap memory

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I saw a simple C program:

```
//create a pointer to 3 bytes on heap
char *start = malloc(3);

*start = 'u';
*(start + 1) = 'v';
*(start + 2) = 'w';

printf("%s has %zu characters.\n", start, strlen(start));

// Free the memory so that it can be reused
free(start);
//Why we need to set start = NULL if we have already freed the memory above
start = NULL;
```

I understand everything except the last line `start = NULL;` , why we need to set it to `NULL`? Is it just to make the pointer point to a `NULL` instead of non-sense memory space?

Is `start = NULL;` a must action or nice-to-have action?

Comment: you have a bug in your code. Your string is not \0 terminated so strlen won't work. You should malloc 4 bytes and set the last to \0 for a string of length 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> Is `start = NULL;` a must action or nice-to-have action?

While not technically required, it's good programming practice to `NULL` the pointer to avoid having a "dangling pointer", a pointer to memory that no longer invalid.

If the `start` variable is immediately falling out of scope (i.e. the dangling pointer is going to immediately disappear), then this is of limited value. But if this `start` variable has a broader scope, it's best practice to `NULL` it.

Comment: You might benefit from reading answer 2 in the duplicate. Or you migh already know it's at best a bad attempt to sweep things under the carpet.

Comment: Lol. That answer is absurd. At best, it's a straw man (no one asked "if I `NULL` my pointers, that fixes all my double `free` problems, right?").

Comment: It's less about that specific failure-mode, and more about whether always nulling out pointers passed to free / delete / at definition time is a good idea.